# Access 2 key data in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can access to the first data of key, but cannot access the next data of key path. When I type 'value' instead of 'child_added' I get data of first path, but I need to access to the all data in the path shown in phot

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          users: []
        }
        this.exportFile = this.exportFile.bind(this)
    }

    componentWillMount(){
      this.getUsers()
      this.getdataIDs()
    }

    getUsers() {
      let users = []

      // uncommented line gives an error
      /*var eventID = firebase.database().ref(`conversationEnrolments`).once('value')*/
      var path = firebase.database().ref(`conversationEnrolments`)
      path.once('child_added', snapshot => {
         snapshot.forEach(snap => {
         users.push(snap.val())
      })
      this.setState({
        users
      })
    })
   }
```

[image: the values of the last path are not displayed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that the `once()` method "listens for exactly one event of the specified event type, and then stops listening." as detailed in the documentation, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once).

So this is why you get only the value for one child, i.e. the one with the `-LDHYq...` id.

If you want to get the entire list of items under the `conversationEnrolments` node, use the `'value'` event and do as follows:

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('conversationEnrolments');
    ref.once('value', function (data) {
        data.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap);
            console.log(snap.val());
        });
    });
```

Then, there is a second problem in your code: Since **the once() method is asynchronous**, and returns a promise (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once)) you need to wait this promise has resolved before being able to use the `users` variable, as follows. Look at the order the different console.log() are executed.

```
    let users = []

    var ref = firebase.database().ref('conversationEnrolments')
    ref.once('value', function (data) {
        data.forEach(snap => {
            console.log(snap);
            console.log(snap.val());
            users.push(snap.val());
        });
    }).then(() => {
        //Here, the promise has resolved and you get the correct value of the users array
        console.log("users AFTER promise has resolved");
        console.log(users);
    })
    console.log("users BEFORE promise has resolved");
    //Here the console.log prints the value of the array before the promise has resolved and.... it is empty!
    console.log(users);
```

---

Update: how to encapsulate this code in a function.

```
    function getUsers() {

        let users = []
        var ref = firebase.database().ref('conversationEnrolments');
        return ref.once('value', function (data) {  //The function returns the result of the promise
            data.forEach(snap => {
                users.push(snap.val());
            });
        }).then(() => {
            return users;  
        })
    }

    //The getUsers() is asynchronous
    //Call it as follows: since it returns a promise, use the result within the then().
    getUsers().then((users) => { console.log(users) });
```

Comment: From console it works perfectly! One problem remaining, cannot push values to the table. Previously, with child_added I could push values to the table, but not now.

Comment: @Jacob What do you exactly mean by "cannot push values". How did you modify your code? Can you update you question by adding the current code (in addition to the original one)

Comment: If you call the `getUsers()` function directly it will return an empty `users` array for the same reason than above. You should organize your code in such a way the `users` array is used only when the promise has resolved.

Comment: @Jacob I've updated my answer to show how to encapsulate the code in a function.